# How to get a 3 variable surface plot of this 5 variable function?

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I am trying to work out the math in an article i'm reading. In the article they use the following mathematical model to describe efficiency in an EC proces, with a,b,c and d being the independent variables and y being the dependant variable:

$$y=92.56+10.87a+15.96b-11.85c+25.96d-1.22ab-9.92ac+4.34ad-6.44bc-0.57bd-0.69cd-29.44a^2-13.25b^2-16.79c^2-21.88d^2$$

In the article they show the following surface plots connected to the model:

https://media.springernature.com/full/springer-static/image/art%3A10.1186%2F2052-336X-12-29/MediaObjects/40201_2013_Article_5045_Fig3_HTML.jpg?as=webp

I am thinking it should be basic calculus getting the plots from the model by keeping 2 variables constant but I can't for the life of me get anything close to the surface plots provided.

Is any one able to see my error or tell me how to handle this problem? Or show me what the surface plots for f(a,b) and g(c,d) should look like?